# Nuxt showing page not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I use the nuxt generate command (npm run generate) to generate the static client side site of my Nuxt project.

```
export default {
  target: 'static',
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,
}
```

in my nuxt.config.js
but when I open the index.html generate is showing nothing and I got this error:
[image]

Any idea on how to solve this !?
Thank,

Comment: Try `npm run start`.

Comment: Try running `npm run dev` command if you are in the development mode.

Comment: @Shreeraj OP generated his project here, no point into running `dev` if the purpose is to try the production build.

Comment: @kissu yep you are right! Agreed

Comment: @kissu am going to production i wish to generate HTML file that i will copy on the server but asset is not showing

Comment: My initial comment is still valid as a local debugging solution. This would be needed on the production server.

Comment: @kissu are you saying that after running the ```npm run generate``` to generate static view them on the server I run the ```npm run start``` ?

Comment: @kissu when i run the ```npm run start``` locally everything is showing well

Comment: Alright, so if you want to have it somewhere else on a production server, you need to do the same `npm run generate && npm run start`.